# Does $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\operatorname{sgn} (x)$ exist?

Tags: limits

I have a problem with this exercise

Does this limit exist?

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0} \operatorname{sgn} (x)$$

this limit should exist and its value is $0$ according to our textbook. It is also written, that we can prove it by using one-sided limits.
And there is a problem, because as I see it

$$\lim_{x\to0^-} \operatorname{sgn} (x) = -1$$

$$\lim_{x\to0^+} \operatorname{sgn} (x) = 1$$

(Because the limit goes very close to $0$, but it never reaches it. I also think it is very similar to prove of non-existence $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} \sin\frac 1 x$)

I also tried online limit calculators and they said, that one-sided limits equals $0$.

Could you help me find a problem in my approach?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The limit does not exist

Comment: You are right, the one-sided limits exist and are different, so the limit itself doesn't exist. If your textbook says otherwise then find a better textbook.

Comment: Your approach is correct. The one-sided limits both exist and are different, so the limit does not exist.

Comment: Which textbook is that?

Comment: but why https://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%200%7D%5Cleft(sgnx%5Cright) then ??

Comment: @martina That limit calculator doesn't understand that "sgn" is a function. It is treating it as the product of three constants, s, g, and n.

Comment: @martina [This](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/limit-calculator/%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto%200%7D%20%5Ctext%7Bsgn%7D%20%5Cleft(x%5Cright)) however returns: "*No Steps: Steps are currently not supported for this problem*".

Comment: Thanks.  And what is different if I have $\lim\limits_{x\to0} x sgn (x)$?

Comment: @martina I entered it as `\sgn (x)` and believe that causes *symbolab* to treat it as the function, but I am not familiar with their syntax. Compare to Wolfram Alpha which does handle the limit correctly [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+sgn(x)+for+x+to+0).

Comment: On suitable definitions $\operatorname{sgn}0=0$, but $\lim_{x\to0}\operatorname{sgn}x$ still doesn't exist. We say $\operatorname{sgn}$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the book says the limit is $0$, then it is wrong.

If $\lim\limits_{x\to0+}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to0-}$ both exist (as finite numbers) and are not equal to each other, then $\lim\limits_{x\to0}$ does not exist.

In some contexts, it might make sense to say it exists as a "principal value", taking an average: $\displaystyle \frac 1 2 \left( \lim_{x\to0+} + \lim_{x\to0-}  \right),$ **but** that is **not** what is conventionally done when the concept of limit is first introduced, and I would allow is **only** when the context for it has been explicitly set.

Answer (score 0):

Q. limx→0sgn(x)

LHS= (0-h)= (-h)= (-1)

RHS= (0+h)
= (h)
= (1)

LHS=-1
RHS=1
Therefore, LHS is not equal to RHS , limit does not exist .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).